# find index of lines in a file in another file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to replace the lines in one file by their **position** or **line number** in another file, which contains the unique elements of the members of the first file.

E.g.

```
file1.txt
----------
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
```

and the second file is

```
labels.txt
----------
A
B
C
```

Then I am trying to get the following output:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
```

I tried some variants of `grep`, but nothing that could do this properly.

Getting the line number for each letter in file1.txt in labels.txt works fine: `grep -n A labels.txt` or `grep -n B labels.txt`

But the moment I try this with both the files as input: `grep -n file1.txt labels.txt` there is no output on the console.

This is of course very simple in Python or something, but a shell version of this would be really useful.(Things like this pop up a lot in making categorical labels from strings of various datasets that can be used to train a classification model etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=NR;next}{print a[$0]}' labels.txt file1.txt
```

the file arguments order is important. While parsing the first input (`FNR==NR`) we store the line number (`NR`) to an array indexed with the line value (`A,B etc`). Then while parsing the second one, that means when `FNR==NR` is false, we print the stored value for the line we find.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to combine `grep` and `awk` like below:

```
for i in `cat file1.txt`;
do
   grep -n label.txt -e $i|awk -F":" '{print $1}';
done
```

Comment: thanks. this works. but the for-loop is more programmatic than shell script, so i chose @thanasisp's answer.

Comment: No problem. It just shows another way to do it and you have rightly chosen @thanasisp's answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can get linenumbers with

```
grep -n . labels.txt
```

Knowing the linenumbers, you can tell what you want

```
grep -n . labels.txt| sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/substitute \2 with \1/'
```

For these substitutions sed needs a commandfile with lines like

```
grep -n . labels.txt| sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/s#^\2$#\1#/'
```

You can use process substitution to skip a temporary file

```
sed -f <(grep -n . labels.txt| sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/s#^\2$#\1#/') file1.txt
```